# Keycloak - Issues syncing users with LDAP

Tags: ldap, keycloak, openldap

I installed Openldap in server and after that added the user into the ldap,below screen show show the added user through Apache Active Directory

[image]

Now in keycloak i added user federation as a openLdap and its connecting to ldap without any issue,but when i am trying to sync the user i am getting message

> Success! Sync of users finished successfully. 0 imported users, 0
>   updated users

So no user import from ldap to keycloak ,below is the related ldap connection information in keycloak .

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to @EricLavault and one of company colleague at last Keycloak able to import the user successfully. Below changes i have done to fix the issue.

1. Change the `User Object Classes=*`
2. Created a new entry `ou=People` then created user under it
3. In Keycloak used  `Users DN = ou=user,ou=people,dc=suredev20`

After this its start throwing below exception

> ERROR [org.keycloak.storage.ldap.LDAPStorageProviderFactory] (default
>   task-1931) Failed during import user from LDAP:
>   org.keycloak.models.ModelException: User returned from LDAP has null
>   username! Check configuration of your LDAP mappings. Mapped username
>   LDAP attribute: uid, user DN:
>   cn=subodh123,ou=user,ou=People,dc=suredev20, attributes from LDAP:
>   {sn=[joshi123], cn=[subodh123], createTimestamp=[20191118180647Z],
>   modifyTimestamp=[20191118180647Z]}

Which is fixed by using `Username LDAP attribute = cn` as ldap username Attribute description in openldap case bydefault `cn`

Answer (score 4):

User entries are not stored correctly in your directory. In fact you shouldn't use `cn=root` as a container as it's supposed to represent the directory manager and should be used for binding and other operations but not for structuring your directory.

Instead, you should use the default user container (at least for OpenLDAP and Apache DS) that is `ou=people,dc=suredev20`, ie. you need to move `cn=subodh`

- from `cn=subodh,ou=user,cn=root,dc=suredev`
- to `cn=subodh,ou=people,dc=suredev20`

Also, in Keycloack you need to set **users dn** accordingly : `ou=people,dc=suredev20`
(you can try with `ou=user,cn=root,dc=suredev` without moving `subodh` entry but not recommended).

Comment: `ou=user,cn=root,dc=suredev20` i tried but still no user import

Comment: That's what I suspected, you need to keep `cn=root,dc=suredev` as a leaf entry and populate users elsewhere in the directory, eg. like suggested in `ou=people,dc=suredev20` but not mandatory.

Comment: Will post what changes i have to done for this,one thing i have to ask how to assign any defult role/group to user imported to keycloak?

Comment: @SubodhJoshi please help us with the answer, I am also getting the same error.

Comment: @MuddesirAhmed Whats your question?